# change variable's value when clicked in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can't change the value of a choice variable when  txtAnswerB div is clicked, here is my code :

```
function checkAnswer(){
    var choice;

    $("#txtAnswerB").click(function() {
        choice = Option2;
        $(this).css("background-color","#fff000");
    });
}
```

ps: option2 is a global variable

Comment: make sure you don't have typos.

Comment: do you have `Option2` in lower or uppercase ?

Comment: `choice` will only exist with the scope of the function `checkAnswer`; is that what you expect?

Comment: Why do you think it's not being changed? I don't see where you're using it. Are you expecting to see some update in the DOM just by changing the variable?

Comment: If I try to alert(choice) I got undefined in the prompt !!

Comment: Option2 is defined outside it's a global variable

Comment: OK..where is alert.. if it is outside `checkAnswer` you have a scope problem. `choice` is currently only available inside that function

Comment: No I alert it inside the checkAnswer function it's weird I don't know why it doesn't work !!

Comment: @DalyChan do you alert `choice` before `choice = Option2;`...??

Comment: is `Option2` global meaning it is outside of $(document).ready()` ?? Would also be scope problem if it is inside a ready handler and `checkAnswer` isn't. Easy test `alert(window.Option2)`

Comment: @BlackCobra I alert after choice = Option2; outside the click handler

Comment: @charlietfl it is not about Optio2 I'm sure I did try to replace that line with : choice= "test"; and still not working

Comment: You need to post more code...where do you call `checkAnswer`. I believe the problem is there. If it is called inside some other handler, the handler for jQuery clcik event won't fire first time

Comment: @DalyChan if you try to alert `choice` outside the `click handler` you will get `undefined`... because the `Element` is not clicked yet... means the event is not happened yet... moreover you will not able to alert `choice` later... because you create it inside the function... after the function have been completed the variable will be removed...

Comment: so how I can test if the element is clicked or not ?

Comment: sorry @DalyChan are you trying triggering click() ? or you want change that on cilck() ?

Comment: How did this question get +2? You need to show a working example of the problem. If you're not willing to do that, then don't bother asking.

Comment: You cant have the click event inside a function... Put it inside document ready.

Comment: @Daly Chan **POST MORE CODE** Stop everyone guessing how you use this. You are wasting everyone's time that are trying to help...yet you won't let us help you. You simply have not provided enough detail in your question, or provided a demo that replicates the problem. I am voting to close this question. If it is closed, please be more thorough next time

Comment: I tried but I coudn't idit my post, I'm sorry if I wasted your time. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

should be somenthing like this

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var choice;
        var Option2 = /*somenthing*/;

        $(function(){
        $("#txtAnswerB").bind('click',function(){
             checkAnswer($(this));
           });
        });

        function checkAnswer(_element){
        choice = Option2;
        $(_element).css("background-color","#fff000");
        alert(choice);

        }
    </script>
```

Comment: +1 I suspect OP is trying to access `choice` outside the function also

Comment: yep but is not well documented the question :P

Comment: @charlietfl: If OP was doing that, the alert wouldn't show up because of the ReferenceError.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the function `checkAnswer();` in order to have `click()` event initialized...

Example:

HTML:

```
<div id="answerB" class="answer"> <div id="txtAnswerB" class="txtAnswer">Quest</div> </div>​
```

jQuery:

```
checkAnswer();
function checkAnswer(){
var choice;
    $("#txtAnswerB").click(function() {
        choice = Option2;
        $(this).css("background-color","red");
    });
}​
```

See live [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/salih0vicX/JraL9/1/)

Comment: where did `checkbox` come into play? OP asked about clicking on a `DIV`

Comment: I didn't use a checkbox here's my html code :
<div id="answerB" class="answer">
   <div id="txtAnswerB" class="txtAnswer">Quest</div>
  </div>

Comment: @Daly Chan I've updated my answer; is that what you were looking for?